# Detect the base of a box pallet

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

[image: here is the image]
I want to recognize the base of a box pallet. I need to identify these three squares. What would be the best approach to do this?
Up to now I got the canny image and looked for square shape contours. Thank you very much.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest square shaped contours since perspective distortion like in this image here will not give you actual squares. Instead since they're on the floor, they'll be the first objects from the bottom, so I'd suggest to change the approach to include that.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Paste some tags on them.

Comment: @Silencer good idea! thanks